# Perpendicularity of the acceleration and velocity vectors given a derivative of a scalar product of two time-dependant vectors

Tags: derivatives, vectors, classical-mechanics

So, Consider a pair of vectors L and M that are dependent on time. Then the scalar product L⋅M is also time-dependent.
Now, coming onto the derivative with respect to time of the scalar product. Show that

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t} (L \cdot M) = \frac{\mathrm{d} L}{\mathrm{d} t} \cdot M + L \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d} M}{\mathrm{d} t} $$

Note: I did this by dividing it into components and then using the product rule and regrouping the values.

But i cant figure out this part:
I cant for one figure out if the velocity and acceleration vectors are either L or M. Secondly, i cant form a proof for this.

Q. Using the derived relation(previous part) express/indicate that if the speed (magnitude of vector velocity) is fixed, then either the acceleration is zero, or acceleration and velocity vectors are in perpendicularity.

Comment: You should see [MSE's page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) (official) and maybe [this](https://math-on-quora.surge.sh/)(unofficial) one for simpler guide to $\LaTeX$.

Comment: Definitely...Future queries would be entered in a proper latex format..

Comment: And write *informative*, searchable titles.

Comment: sure... going to edit the title..

Answer (score 1):

Try $L = M = v$ the velocity. Then $L \cdot M = v^2$ is the speed (squared). Now what does your formula tell you?

Comment: 2v multiplied by dv/dt   ... but how does this act as a proof? I still cant relate it to acceleration..

Comment: dv/dt is the acceleration

Comment: but how can i show through this that the acceleration vector(dv/dt) is perpendicular to the velocity vector?

Comment: what does it mean if the dot product of two vectors is zero?

Comment: both are perpendicular, ohhh i get it...

Comment: so v is velocity vector and dv/dt is acceleration vector and 2 is a constant.  if v is constant than dv/dt is 0.

Comment: careful the problem gives you that the speed $v^2$ is constant not necessarily $v$ it could be changing direction

Comment: yes, +v and -v, this would indicate a change in acceleration, that is why it was mentioned as speed. but v^2 is essentially speed as sign is ignored,right?

Comment: I am assuming you are working with 3D velocity in which case $v^2 = v \cdot v$ is the length of the velocity vector

Comment: its two dimensional velocity..

Comment: In any number of dimensions, the dot product of a vector $v$ with itself is the square of its MAGNITUDE, which is the speed squared when $v$ is (vector) velocity.

Comment: One last thing, why did we consider l and m to be velocity?, i mean both would depend differently to time...